# Java FileSystemPreferencesFactory in windows

Tags: java

When running on Windows how can I change the Preferences that they will be as file and not in registry?

Sometimes there is Windows hardening and customers cannot access the regedit.

Comment: What Preferences are you talking about?

Comment: user
Preferences.systemRoot().node

Answer (score 2):

The Java documentation for `Preferences` tells you how to implement your own `PreferencesFactory`.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html

> Every Preferences implementation must have an associated
>   PreferencesFactory implementation. Every Java(TM) SE implementation
>   must provide some means of specifying which PreferencesFactory
>   implementation is used to generate the root preferences nodes. This
>   allows the administrator to replace the default preferences
>   implementation with an alternative implementation.
>
> **Implementation Note:**
>       The PreferencesFactory implementation is located as follows:
>
> If the system property java.util.prefs.PreferencesFactory is defined, then it is taken to be the fully-qualified name of a class
>   implementing the PreferencesFactory interface. The class is loaded and
>   instantiated; if this process fails then an unspecified error is
>   thrown.
>
> If a PreferencesFactory implementation class file has been installed in a jar file that is visible to the system class loader,
>   and that jar file contains a provider-configuration file named
>   java.util.prefs.PreferencesFactory in the resource directory
>   META-INF/services, then the first class name specified in that file is
>   taken. If more than one such jar file is provided, the first one found
>   will be used. The class is loaded and instantiated; if this process
>   fails then an unspecified error is thrown.
>
> Finally, if neither the above-mentioned system property nor an extension jar file is provided, then the system-wide default
>   PreferencesFactory implementation for the underlying platform is
>   loaded and instantiated.

Comment: but FileSystemPreferencesFactory is already implemented , and I want to use it

Comment: @li-raz You can select the desired `PreferencesFactory` as mentioned in the documentation linked and quoted.